# Updated from El Capitan to Sierra (10.11 to 10.12) and now no login passwords work

Tags: macos, high-sierra, password, keychain, login

I have an older Mac Pro that I’ve been meaning to update for quite some time so I downloaded the Sierra installer and updated it.

It appears the update goes fine and the system restarts but none of my passwords for any of the accounts on the computer will work.

I’ve tried using my Apple ID to reset the passwords, it appears to happen but it never works.

I’ve tried using the "Master password" which I know I have right because if I leave off a character it tells me it’s wrong.  I click the **Change password** button but nothing happens.

I’ve tried using the resetPassword tool in Recovery mode. It says it changes it but when it reboots it doesn’t fix the issue.

I’ve tried the `delete var/db/.AppleSetupDone` trick and all that gets me is a black screen on boot and the only way around it is to restore or copy the `var/db/.AppleSetupDone` file from my Time Machine backup.

I’ve tried updating to High Sierra but that made no difference.

I’ve restored back to a Time Machine backup about 7 times trying everything:

- FileVault on: when starting up, it accepts the FileVault password but after that, it doesn’t accept any of the account passwords.
- FileVault off. Same, no difference.
- I tried to set auto login for all the accounts but that doesn’t work after the update.
- I’ve tried creating a new admin account before updating with a short simple name and a short simple password but it does the same thing.

I can’t find any solution or hack for this.

Comment: Which Mac Pro, precisely? Is it still stock GPU etc? Have you thought of running a clean install & then Migrating rather than restoring? If you set up a temp admin account to start with, test that before running migration.

Comment: It’s an early 2009.  I finally got around to buying an old graphics card so I could update the firmware from 4,1 to 5,1 so I could update past El Capitan. 

I haven’t done a clean install. I’ve tried reinstalling the OS from recovery mode but it fails - I think clean install and migration might be a good option

Comment: Depending on exactly which GPU you got, switch off Filevault before updating/installing. If you can usually see the screen before login, you should be OK. If not, filevault will break your ability to login at all. If you have a Mac-flashed ATI/AMD card you should be fine. If it's NVidia, then make sure you get exactly the right drivers - http://www.macvidcards.com/drivers.html 4,1 vs 5,1 firmware shouldn't be a dealbreaker at High Sierra, only at Mojave. NVidia never made any drivers for Mojave, though, so that would make it even more important to have a flashed AMD.

Comment: I bought one of the original graphics cards from this model off eBay: Apple Mac Pro A1310 NVIDIA GeForce GT 120

Comment: Ah, OK. No issues with Filevault then - but that's really a 'base spec' card & can't do Mojave, so your pinnacle to aim for is High Sierra.

Comment: I have a much higher end GPU card but I figured while I’m troubleshooting use the stock card to eliminate possible issues. 

FileVault accepts my password without hesitation but it’s after that where it won’t accept any of the accounts/passwords

Comment: I'd give the clean install a go - avoid Filevault [just in case] & see how the first account behaves. Then mod it by migrating the 'real' accounts.

Comment: yeah, I'm doing a clean install and then if it goes okay I'll try to migrate from my Time Machine backup

Comment: I did a clean install and created a new user and everything under 10.12 worked fine. Did updates, restarted multiple times -- all fine.

I used the migration assistant to bring over my accounts, files and applications from my Time Machine back up and after that it went into a reboot loop.

Ran disk first aid multiple times from recovery but nothing worked.

I just erased the drive and am doing another clean install....  no idea what's causing this.  When I do a full restore from TM it goes fine and all the accounts and applications work fine under El Capitan.

Comment: Sounds like you've got something that hits an incompatibility after El Cap - but there should be no 'brick wall' for anything at that point. Mojave is the brick wall for 32-bit apps. I really can't think of anything else that would suddenly be hard incompatible. I think you're going to have to reinstall apps rather than migrate them. Docs etc should be OK. Not sure what else to suggest, sorry.

Comment: No matter what I tried I had to do a clean install, recreated all the user accounts, re-install the applications and copy over by hand all my files.

I was never able to put a finger on what was causing this but I have seen some people suggest it was keychain related. What a pain in the a$$. So much wasted time.